# React: after deleting element from array deleted element is shown

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm having strange issue after deleting an element from array , the same element is shown in the UI but the element is being deleted from array.

I have already seen this : [React rendering deleted array element after setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135598/react-rendering-deleted-array-element-after-setstate)

this is the gif [image]

**this is how I delete the element:**

```
const deleteTaglia = useCallback(
    (i) => {
      let arraytaglie = variant.taglie;
      arraytaglie.splice(i, 1);
      setVariant((pv) => {
        return { ...pv, taglie: arraytaglie };
      });
    },
    [variant.taglie]
  );
```

**this is where I render my array:**

```
{variant.taglie.map((v, i) => (
                <Taglia
                  key={i}
                  singleTaglia={v}
                  index={i}
                  addOrUpdateTaglia={addOrUpdateTaglia}
                  deleteTaglia={deleteTaglia}
                />
              ))}
```

**this is my state:**

```
const [variant, setVariant] = useState({
    color: "",
    codiceArticolo: "",
    ean: "",
    imagesVariant: [],
    taglie: [],
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.splice` modifies the array "in place" (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)), so when you call `setState` the change *within* your array doesn't cause a re-render (because the reference to the array doesn't change). Instead, you need to replace the array itself. There are a few options, but the smallest change from your current code is just to create a new array using the spread operator:

```
const deleteTaglia = useCallback(
    (i) => {
      let arraytaglie = variant.taglie;
      arraytaglie.splice(i, 1);
      setVariant((pv) => {
        return { ...pv, taglie: [...arraytaglie] };
      });
    },
    [variant.taglie]
  );
```

In addition, using an index for a key can also create problems when adding/removing items as it isn't clear that the object the you have deleted is no longer in the position it was (as the `key` is used to detect changes). Change the `key` property to something unique to each item and your delete will lead to an update as you expect.

Comment: have added another modification that you need